# React Native iOS app calls Google Cloud STT API

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I am building an iOS app using react native and expo. When I am trying to call Google Cloud Speech to Text API from the client side by importing @@google-cloud/speech, it gives me an error

*"The package at "node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/build/src/helpers.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "stream". It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library."*

Does it mean that it is no way to directly call STT API from the client side. I have to set a server listening on the cloud so that google can charge me more $? Anyone have experience on that or any suggestions?